# Single Process Multi Thread communication

Tags: android, multithreading

What are the pros and cons of using Message Passing or Shared Memory?

In my Android App I am using Message Passing where a thread keep a FIFO queue where other thread take a lock to insert message and the consumer reads messages and do whatever must do.

Some colleagues suggest me to use directly a shared memory where each thread locks the data structure and insert directly datas, their reason is that this is simpler to do.

I find that the my solution is more elegant and allows to separate better the responsabilities between different threads (producers and consumers) what do you think?

Comment: I think you guys are all reimplementing `HandlerThread` + `Handler`. and I don't see why.

Comment: Probably because I am a noob in Android Framework, I know better Java. Thank you for help i'll take a look on HandlerThread.